# Javascript: How do I code a script where the user inputs a number and it returns three other numbers?

Tags: javascript

I'm not even quite sure how I can make myself clear and I do apologize... but I have been searching all over the internet for a similar JavaScript code and I'm not even quite sure how to phrase the question ...

Basically, I want the user to input one thing, and I want something else to pop up.

As an example, the user would type in a number, let's say "10" into a text field or drop-down menu and then three other numbers would pop up, such as 15.25, 16.50, and 17.75 (either in pop window form, or just in a plain sentence, or in other text fields ... it doesn't really matter).

What I'm doing is I want to post an estimate calculator for loan payments on a website (with options for 30 day, 60 day, and 90 day payoff options).

There's no math involved in this code whatsoever (I understand if I have to input a lot of numbers - I already have those!). I don't want to create a calculator, because I think a calculator would be more complicated (I'm aiming for simple!) ... The loan fees and interest vary from one group of numbers to another, so if it were to be a calculator the script might get really complicated (because we're not looking at a easy 1 + 1 = 2 equation ... it's more like 1 + 1.50 + 1.00 = 3.50, or 10.00 + 4.00 + 1.25 = 15.25, or even 30.00 + 6.00 + 1.75 etc., there's no consistency).

So I'm figuring a simpler way around this beast would be to have the numbers readily available, with no calculations. So if they enter in a 1, the result they would get be 3.50, 4.50, and 5.50.

I don't know, that might be asking a bit much too....

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: What have you tried? Why would you not want to write the function to CALCULATE the price once, even if it is complex, rather than try to predict EVERY SINGLE VALUE that one may want to enter into your field?

Comment: Your table of data is going to be huge.  Looking that up with javascript would be HARDER than doing the loan payment calculation.  Th math/formula is not actually terribly complicated, and readily available on the internet with a bit of searching.

Comment: do you want calculations based on `if they enter in a 1, the result they would get be 3.50, 4.50, and 5.50.` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a *simplest* form it will look like this:

```
var magic_box = {
    '1': [3.50, 4.50, 5.50],
    '2': [2.50, 34.50, 5.55],
    '3': [1.50, 0.50, 15.50]
};

var what = prompt( 'Tell me the magic number!' );
alert( magic_box[ what ] );
```

We use hash-map (aka javascript object) each element of which is an array, and each element of those arrays is your desired number.

Then, we give user a popup with question and store his answer (or his *input*) into variable.

Then we use this variable as a key for our hash-map.

---

*p.s.: there are several issues with solutions above, so its purely for educational reasons.*

Answer (score 0):

building on @c69's answer, if there is a range for each set of numbers then add min, max values to the three numbers, loop through array, do an inclusion check, stop on row where number is in range

Comment: offtopic: _maybe a bug ? also, try refreshing page._